# Quartz 2D Drawing: Overlapping lines/curve don't blend

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

Drawing an overlapping path in a single stroke doesn't produce the same result if i draw multiple overlapping paths. I want the overlapping path to blend (even if user is creating that path in a single stroke). How can i do that?

See attached picture for reference.

1. In the first line, you can see that the color of overlapping parts
   **is** blending.
2. In the second line, you can see that the color of overlapping parts **is not** blending.

Logic used t draw the path:
I create a `UIBezierPath` every time user touches and moves his finger. I stroke the path to my view when user is done. So, for example, in the first line, the text consists of more than one `UIBezierPath`s, but in case of second line, it's a single `UIBezierPath`.

[image]

**Edit:** Another example (Blending vs. Non-Blending).
[image]